# Save an object with pickle which is returned by function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

How can I save the model which is returned from the function regarding the defined method class? I would like to make the same wrapper for many classes similar to (in my case) Rocket class.

The code below produces an error:
Can't pickle local object 'sktime_wrapper..SKtimeWrapper'

```
import pickle
from sktime.transformations.panel.rocket import Rocket
from sktime.datatypes._panel._convert import from_2d_array_to_nested

def sktime_wrapper(method_class):
    class SKtimeWrapper(method_class):
        def transform(self, X):
            X = from_2d_array_to_nested(X)
            return super().transform(X)

        def fit(self, X, Y):
            X = from_2d_array_to_nested(X)
            return super().fit(X, Y)

    return SKtimeWrapper


model = sktime_wrapper(Rocket)

with open('model.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

In case when class is defined as top-level object, the pickle works just fine. The code below works like a charm and saves the model without any problem:

```
import pickle
from sktime.transformations.panel.rocket import Rocket
from sktime.datatypes._panel._convert import from_2d_array_to_nested

class SKtimeWrapper(Rocket):
    def transform(self, X):
        X = from_2d_array_to_nested(X)
        return super().transform(X)

    def fit(self, X, Y):
        X = from_2d_array_to_nested(X)
        return super().fit(X, Y)

model = SKtimeWrapper


with open('model.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

Comment: This might help: [How to pickle an instance of a class which is written inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807004/how-to-pickle-an-instance-of-a-class-which-is-written-inside-a-function)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer redirected me to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526524/6274417)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the answers section, I managed to make it work! I hope somebody finds this useful. The trick is to use `__reduce__()` function.

Bellow is a working example. Beware that the object must be initialized before saving.

```
import pickle
from sktime.transformations.panel.rocket import Rocket
from sktime.datatypes._panel._convert import from_2d_array_to_nested

def sktime_wrapper(method_class):
    class SKtimeWrapper(method_class):
        PARAM = method_class
        def transform(self, X):
            X = from_2d_array_to_nested(X)
            return super().transform(X)

        def fit(self, X, Y):
            X = from_2d_array_to_nested(X)
            return super().fit(X, Y)

        def __reduce__(self):
            return (_InitializeParameterized(), (self.PARAM,), self.__dict__)

    return SKtimeWrapper

class _InitializeParameterized(object):
    """
    When called with the param value as the only argument, returns an
    un-initialized instance of the parameterized class. Subsequent __setstate__
    will be called by pickle.
    """
    def __call__(self, method_class):
        # make a simple object which has no complex __init__ (this one will do)
        obj = _InitializeParameterized()
        obj.__class__ = sktime_wrapper(method_class)
        return obj


model = sktime_wrapper(Rocket)()

with open('model.pkl','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```