# Pickling and Unpickling a dynamically generated class

Tags: python, class, pickle, factory

I have a function that returns a customized class type which I then want to pickle and unpickle. I am trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526524/2260153) and the [`__reduce__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__). I am using Python 2.7.
The difference from that answer is that my function accepts an arbitrary class and returns a class derived from it. This is what I have:

```
class Base(object):
    def foo(self, a):
        return a + 1

    def __reduce__(self):
        return _InitializeDynamicClass(), (), self.__dict__


def get_dynamic_class(BaseClass):  # BaseClass can be any class derived from Base, or Base itself
    class DynamicClass(BaseClass):
        def foo(self, a):
            return BaseClass.foo(self, a) + 2
    return DynamicClass


class _InitializeDynamicClass(object):
    def __call__(self, param_value):
        obj = _InitializeDynamicClass()
        obj.__class__ = get_dynamic_class(Base)  # giving Base here is probably wrong, but how can I fix it?
        return obj


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pickle import dumps, loads

    dynamic_instance = get_dynamic_class(Base)()
    dynamic_instance_dump = dumps(dynamic_instance)
    del dynamic_instance
    dynamic_instance = loads(dynamic_instance_dump)  # raises TypeError
```

The `dumps` command works but the `loads` command raises a `TypeError`:

```
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How can I overcome this? If this problem stems from a basic design flaw, how would I restructure this code to enable serialization of instances of dynamically generated classes?