# Serialize an instance of a python metaclass

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, metaclass, python-dataclasses, dill

#### Questions

- How can I serialize an instance of a data class in a way that saves its state when the state is generated by its meta class?

  - See description and sample code for more clarification.
- How do I share context in python in a way that replicates the `working-case` while achieving the modularity of the `sample-issue` case?

  - [Context sharing reference](https://python-list.python.narkive.com/ibjVxgBH/pickling-instances-of-metaclass-generated-classes)
- Is there an alternative way of populating data classes in an abstract way that doesn't use meta classes?

  - Needs to be abstracted because I have multiple data classes that are representative of request information that are all populated in a similar fashion.

#### Description

I am currently writing a flask web application that passes processing of tasks off to rq workers via a redis queue (using `rq`), and I am having trouble with the serialization of the data classes that contain the request information. The issue I am running into happens when `rq` tries to serialize a data class that uses a meta class to populate all of its fields.

When debugging and diagnosing the issue I have noticed that `dill`, and `cloudpickle` are able to serialize the instance of the object correctly when the instance is created and defined in the same file/module, but once I move the definition of the object to a different file/module they are unable to serialize the object in a way that maintains the instances state.

I have added a simplified sample below to replicate my problem.

#### Environment

```
Python Version: python 3.7.3
OS: Windows

# File structure
\sample-issue
--> dataclass.py
--> serialization.py
--> deserialization.py
--> __init__.py

\working-case
--> sample.py
--> __init__.py
```

#### Sample Issue

```
# dataclass.py

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List, Dict, Any
import json
from collections import defaultdict


class JSONRequest(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This is a metaclass used to autonomously populate dataclasses

        NOTE: This metaclass only works with dataclasses

        Optional Parameter:
            inp: class attribute that is a callable that produces a dictionary
        """
        inp = cls.__dict__["inp"]()
        cls.__initialize(inp)
        return cls

    def __initialize(cls, inp: dict) -> None:
        """
        Initializes all of the dataclasses fields

        If the field is missing in the JSON request and it does not have a default value in the data class a
        ValueError error will be raised. Additionally if the Json value is [], {}, "" will default to the default
        value, and if the default value is missing an InvalidRequest error will also be raised.

        Parameters:
            inp: Json input
        """
        _json = defaultdict(lambda: None)
        _json.update(inp)

        for name, _ in cls.__dataclass_fields__.items():
            if (not _json[name]) and (name not in cls.__dict__.keys()):
                raise ValueError(f"Request is missing the {name} field")

            value = _json[name] or cls.__dict__[name]
            setattr(cls, name, value)

    def __str__(cls):
        rep = {name: getattr(cls, name) for name, _ in cls.__dataclass_fields__.items()}
        return json.dumps(rep, indent=4)


def generate_input():
    """
    Stub method for generating input
    """
    return {
        "email_list": [f"{name}@yahoo.com" for name in ["peter", "mark", "alysa"]],
        "message": "Foo bar fizzbuzz",
        "subject": "Sample Issue",
        "info": {
            "time": 1619628747.9166002,
            "count": 3,
        }
    }


@dataclass
class EmailChain(metaclass=JSONRequest):
    email_list: List[str] = field(init=False)
    message: str = field(init=False)
    subject: str = field(init=False)
    info: Dict[str, Any] = field(init=False)

    inp = generate_input
```

```
# serialization.py

import dill
from sample_issue.dataclass import EmailChain

obj = EmailChain()
data_stream = dill.dumps(obj)
print(data_stream) 

# output: b'\x80\x03csrc.Test\nEmailChain\nq\x00.'
```

```
# deserialization

import dill
from sample_issue.dataclass import EmailChain

input = b'\x80\x03csrc.Test\nEmailChain\nq\x00.'
obj = dill.loads(input)
print(obj)

# Results in error since obj is missing data class fields for __str__ method
```

#### Working Case

```
# Working-case

import dill
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List, Dict, Any
import json
from collections import defaultdict


class JSONRequest(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This is a metaclass used to autonomously populate dataclasses

        NOTE: This metaclass only works with dataclasses

        Optional Parameter:
            inp: class attribute that is a callable that produces a dictionary
        """
        inp = cls.__dict__["inp"]()
        cls.__initialize(inp)
        return cls

    def __initialize(cls, inp: dict) -> None:
        """
        Initializes all of the dataclasses fields

        If the field is missing in the JSON request and it does not have a default value in the data class a
        ValueError error will be raised. Additionally if the Json value is [], {}, "" will default to the default
        value, and if the default value is missing an InvalidRequest error will also be raised.

        Parameters:
            inp: Json input
        """
        _json = defaultdict(lambda: None)
        _json.update(inp)

        for name, _ in cls.__dataclass_fields__.items():
            if (not _json[name]) and (name not in cls.__dict__.keys()):
                raise ValueError(f"Request is missing the {name} field")

            value = _json[name] or cls.__dict__[name]
            setattr(cls, name, value)

    def __str__(cls):
        rep = {name: getattr(cls, name) for name, _ in cls.__dataclass_fields__.items()}
        return json.dumps(rep, indent=4)


def generate_input():
    """
    Stub method for generating input
    """
    return {
        "email_list": [f"{name}@yahoo.com" for name in ["peter", "mark", "alysa"]],
        "message": "Foo bar fizzbuzz",
        "subject": "Sample Issue",
        "info": {
            "time": 1619628747.9166002,
            "count": 3,
        }
    }


@dataclass
class EmailChain(metaclass=JSONRequest):
    email_list: List[str] = field(init=False)
    message: str = field(init=False)
    subject: str = field(init=False)
    info: Dict[str, Any] = field(init=False)

    inp = generate_input


obj = EmailChain()
data_stream = dill.dumps(obj)
print(data_stream)

# output: b'\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(h\x00(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x04\x00\x00\x00typeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04X\x0b\x00\x00\x00JSONRequestq\x05h\x04\x85q\x06}q\x07(X\n\x00\x00\x00__module__q\x08X\x08\x00\x00\x00__main__q\tX\x08\x00\x00\x00__call__q\ncdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x0b(cdill._dill\n_create_code\nq\x0c(K\x01K\x00K\x04K\x03KOC\x1a|\x00j\x00d\x01\x19\x00\x83\x00}\x03|\x00\xa0\x01|\x03\xa1\x01\x01\x00|\x00S\x00q\rX\xf5\x00\x00\x00\n        This is a metaclass used to autonomously populate dataclasses\n\n        NOTE: This metaclass only works with dataclasses\n\n        Optional Parameter:\n            inp: class attribute that is a callable that produces a dictionary\n        q\x0eX\x03\x00\x00\x00inpq\x0f\x86q\x10X\x08\x00\x00\x00__dict__q\x11X\x18\x00\x00\x00_JSONRequest__initializeq\x12\x86q\x13(X\x03\x00\x00\x00clsq\x14X\x04\x00\x00\x00argsq\x15X\x06\x00\x00\x00kwargsq\x16h\x0ftq\x17XL\x00\x00\x00C:/Users/739908/Work/systems_automation/report_automation_engine/src/temp.pyq\x18h\nK\nC\x06\x00\t\x0c\x01\n\x01q\x19))tq\x1aRq\x1bc__builtin__\n__main__\nh\nNN}q\x1cNtq\x1dRq\x1eh\x12h\x0b(h\x0c(K\x02K\x00K\x06K\x05KCCvt\x00d\x01d\x02\x84\x00\x83\x01}\x02|\x02\xa0\x01|\x01\xa1\x01\x01\x00xZ|\x00j\x02\xa0\x03\xa1\x00D\x00]L\\\x02}\x03}\x04|\x02|\x03\x19\x00sP|\x03|\x00j\x04\xa0\x05\xa1\x00k\x07rPt\x06d\x03|\x03\x9b\x00d\x04\x9d\x03\x83\x01\x82\x01|\x02|\x03\x19\x00p`|\x00j\x04|\x03\x19\x00}\x05t\x07|\x00|\x03|\x05\x83\x03\x01\x00q"W\x00d\x05S\x00q\x1f(X\xac\x01\x00\x00\n        Initializes all of the dataclasses fields\n\n        If the field is missing in the JSON request and it does not have a default value in the data class a\n        ValueError error will be raised. Additionally if the Json value is [], {}, "" will default to the default\n        value, and if the default value is missing an InvalidRequest error will also be raised.\n\n        Parameters:\n            inp: Json input\n        q h\x0c(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x01KSC\x04d\x00S\x00q!N\x85q"))h\x18X\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q#K"C\x00q$))tq%Rq&X*\x00\x00\x00JSONRequest.__initialize.<locals>.<lambda>q\'X\x17\x00\x00\x00Request is missing the q(X\x06\x00\x00\x00 fieldq)Ntq*(X\x0b\x00\x00\x00defaultdictq+X\x06\x00\x00\x00updateq,X\x14\x00\x00\x00__dataclass_fields__q-X\x05\x00\x00\x00itemsq.h\x11X\x04\x00\x00\x00keysq/X\n\x00\x00\x00ValueErrorq0X\x07\x00\x00\x00setattrq1tq2(h\x14h\x0fX\x05\x00\x00\x00_jsonq3X\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq4X\x01\x00\x00\x00_q5X\x05\x00\x00\x00valueq6tq7h\x18X\x0c\x00\x00\x00__initializeq8K\x17C\x0e\x00\x0b\x0c\x01\n\x02\x14\x01\x16\x01\x10\x02\x12\x01q9))tq:Rq;c__builtin__\n__main__\nh8NN}q<Ntq=Rq>X\x07\x00\x00\x00__str__q?h\x0b(h\x0c(K\x01K\x00K\x02K\x04K\x03C&\x87\x00f\x01d\x01d\x02\x84\x08\x88\x00j\x00\xa0\x01\xa1\x00D\x00\x83\x01}\x01t\x02j\x03|\x01d\x03d\x04\x8d\x02S\x00q@(Nh\x0c(K\x01K\x00K\x03K\x05K\x13C\x1ci\x00|\x00]\x14\\\x02}\x01}\x02t\x00\x88\x00|\x01\x83\x02|\x01\x93\x02q\x04S\x00qA)X\x07\x00\x00\x00getattrqB\x85qCX\x02\x00\x00\x00.0qDh4h5\x87qEh\x18X\n\x00\x00\x00<dictcomp>qFK-C\x02\x06\x00qGh\x14\x85qH)tqIRqJX\'\x00\x00\x00JSONRequest.__str__.<locals>.<dictcomp>qKK\x04X\x06\x00\x00\x00indentqL\x85qMtqN(h-h.X\x04\x00\x00\x00jsonqOX\x05\x00\x00\x00dumpsqPtqQh\x14X\x03\x00\x00\x00repqR\x86qSh\x18h?K,C\x04\x00\x01\x18\x01qT)h\x14\x85qUtqVRqWc__builtin__\n__main__\nh?NN}qXNtqYRqZX\x07\x00\x00\x00__doc__q[Nutq\\Rq]X\n\x00\x00\x00EmailChainq^h\x01X\x06\x00\x00\x00objectq_\x85q`Rqa\x85qb}qc(h\x08h\tX\x0f\x00\x00\x00__annotations__qd}qe(X\n\x00\x00\x00email_listqfcdill._dill\n_get_attr\nqgcdill._dill\n_import_module\nqhX\t\x00\x00\x00_operatorqi\x85qjRqkX\x07\x00\x00\x00getitemql\x86qmRqnctyping\nList\nqoh\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00strqp\x85qqRqr\x86qsRqtX\x07\x00\x00\x00messagequhrX\x07\x00\x00\x00subjectqvhrX\x04\x00\x00\x00infoqwhnctyping\nDict\nqxhrctyping\nAny\nqy\x86qz\x86q{Rq|uh\x0fh\x0b(h\x0c(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x06KCC\x1ed\x01d\x02\x84\x00d\x03D\x00\x83\x01d\x04d\x05d\x06d\x07d\x08\x9c\x02d\t\x9c\x04S\x00q}(X*\x00\x00\x00\n    Stub method for generating input\n    q~h\x0c(K\x01K\x00K\x02K\x04KSC\x16g\x00|\x00]\x0e}\x01|\x01\x9b\x00d\x00\x9d\x02\x91\x02q\x04S\x00q\x7fX\n\x00\x00\x00@yahoo.comq\x80\x85q\x81)hDh4\x86q\x82h\x18X\n\x00\x00\x00<listcomp>q\x83K6C\x02\x06\x00q\x84))tq\x85Rq\x86X"\x00\x00\x00generate_input.<locals>.<listcomp>q\x87X\x05\x00\x00\x00peterq\x88X\x04\x00\x00\x00markq\x89X\x05\x00\x00\x00alysaq\x8a\x87q\x8bX\x10\x00\x00\x00Foo bar fizzbuzzq\x8cX\x0c\x00\x00\x00Sample Issueq\x8dGA\xd8"d\xb2\xfa\xa9\x94K\x03X\x04\x00\x00\x00timeq\x8eX\x05\x00\x00\x00countq\x8f\x86q\x90(hfhuhvhwtq\x91tq\x92))h\x18X\x0e\x00\x00\x00generate_inputq\x93K1C\n\x00\x05\x0c\x01\x02\x01\x02\x02\x02\x01q\x94))tq\x95Rq\x96c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x93NN}q\x97Ntq\x98Rq\x99h[X\x1b\x00\x00\x00EmailChain(*args, **kwargs)q\x9aX\x14\x00\x00\x00__dataclass_params__q\x9bcdataclasses\n_DataclassParams\nq\x9c)\x81q\x9dN}q\x9e(X\x04\x00\x00\x00initq\x9f\x88X\x04\x00\x00\x00reprq\xa0\x88X\x02\x00\x00\x00eqq\xa1\x88X\x05\x00\x00\x00orderq\xa2\x89X\x0b\x00\x00\x00unsafe_hashq\xa3\x89X\x06\x00\x00\x00frozenq\xa4\x89u\x86q\xa5bh-}q\xa6(hfcdataclasses\nField\nq\xa7)\x81q\xa8N}q\xa9(h4hfh\x02htX\x07\x00\x00\x00defaultq\xaacdataclasses\n_MISSING_TYPE\nq\xab)\x81q\xacX\x0f\x00\x00\x00default_factoryq\xadh\xach\xa0\x88X\x04\x00\x00\x00hashq\xaeNh\x9f\x89X\x07\x00\x00\x00compareq\xaf\x88X\x08\x00\x00\x00metadataq\xb0h\x01X\x10\x00\x00\x00MappingProxyTypeq\xb1\x85q\xb2Rq\xb3}q\xb4\x85q\xb5Rq\xb6X\x0b\x00\x00\x00_field_typeq\xb7cdataclasses\n_FIELD_BASE\nq\xb8)\x81q\xb9}q\xbah4X\x06\x00\x00\x00_FIELDq\xbbsbu\x86q\xbcbhuh\xa7)\x81q\xbdN}q\xbe(h4huh\x02hrh\xaah\xach\xadh\xach\xa0\x88h\xaeNh\x9f\x89h\xaf\x88h\xb0h\xb6h\xb7h\xb9u\x86q\xbfbhvh\xa7)\x81q\xc0N}q\xc1(h4hvh\x02hrh\xaah\xach\xadh\xach\xa0\x88h\xaeNh\x9f\x89h\xaf\x88h\xb0h\xb6h\xb7h\xb9u\x86q\xc2bhwh\xa7)\x81q\xc3N}q\xc4(h4hwh\x02h|h\xaah\xach\xadh\xach\xa0\x88h\xaeNh\x9f\x89h\xaf\x88h\xb0h\xb6h\xb7h\xb9u\x86q\xc5buX\x08\x00\x00\x00__init__q\xc6h\x0b(h\x0c(K\x01K\x00K\x01K\x01KCC\x04d\x00S\x00q\xc7N\x85q\xc8)X\x04\x00\x00\x00selfq\xc9\x85q\xcaX\x08\x00\x00\x00<string>q\xcbh\xc6K\x01C\x02\x00\x01q\xcc))tq\xcdRq\xce}q\xcf(X\x07\x00\x00\x00MISSINGq\xd0h\xacX\x14\x00\x00\x00_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORYq\xd1cdataclasses\n_HAS_DEFAULT_FACTORY_CLASS\nq\xd2)\x81q\xd3X\x0c\x00\x00\x00__builtins__q\xd4hhX\x08\x00\x00\x00builtinsq\xd5\x85q\xd6Rq\xd7uh\xc6NN}q\xd8Ntq\xd9Rq\xdaX\x08\x00\x00\x00__repr__q\xdbh\x0b(h\x0c(K\x01K\x00K\x03K\tK\x13CDt\x00|\x00\x83\x01t\x01\xa0\x02\xa1\x00f\x02}\x01|\x01\x88\x00k\x06r\x1cd\x01S\x00\x88\x00\xa0\x03|\x01\xa1\x01\x01\x00z\x0c\x88\x01|\x00\x83\x01}\x02W\x00d\x00\x88\x00\xa0\x04|\x01\xa1\x01\x01\x00X\x00|\x02S\x00q\xdcNX\x03\x00\x00\x00...q\xdd\x86q\xde(X\x02\x00\x00\x00idq\xdfX\x07\x00\x00\x00_threadq\xe0X\t\x00\x00\x00get_identq\xe1X\x03\x00\x00\x00addq\xe2X\x07\x00\x00\x00discardq\xe3tq\xe4h\xc9X\x03\x00\x00\x00keyq\xe5X\x06\x00\x00\x00resultq\xe6\x87q\xe7X\'\x00\x00\x00C:\\DevApps\\Python3.7\\lib\\dataclasses.pyq\xe8X\x07\x00\x00\x00wrapperq\xe9M^\x01C\x10\x00\x02\x10\x01\x08\x01\x04\x01\n\x01\x02\x01\x0c\x02\x0c\x01q\xeaX\x0c\x00\x00\x00repr_runningq\xebX\r\x00\x00\x00user_functionq\xec\x86q\xed)tq\xeeRq\xefcdataclasses\n__dict__\nh\xdbNcdill._dill\n_create_cell\nq\xf0h\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00setq\xf1\x85q\xf2Rq\xf3]q\xf4\x85q\xf5Rq\xf6\x85q\xf7Rq\xf8h\xf0h\x0b(h\x0c(K\x01K\x00K\x01K\nKCC.|\x00j\x00j\x01d\x01|\x00j\x02\x9b\x02d\x02|\x00j\x03\x9b\x02d\x03|\x00j\x04\x9b\x02d\x04|\x00j\x05\x9b\x02d\x05\x9d\t\x17\x00S\x00q\xf9(NX\x0c\x00\x00\x00(email_list=q\xfaX\n\x00\x00\x00, message=q\xfbX\n\x00\x00\x00, subject=q\xfcX\x07\x00\x00\x00, info=q\xfdX\x01\x00\x00\x00)q\xfetq\xff(X\t\x00\x00\x00__class__r\x00\x01\x00\x00X\x0c\x00\x00\x00__qualname__r\x01\x01\x00\x00hfhuhvhwtr\x02\x01\x00\x00h\xc9\x85r\x03\x01\x00\x00h\xcbh\xdbK\x01C\x02\x00\x01r\x04\x01\x00\x00))tr\x05\x01\x00\x00Rr\x06\x01\x00\x00cdataclasses\n__dict__\nh\xdbNN}r\x07\x01\x00\x00Ntr\x08\x01\x00\x00Rr\t\x01\x00\x00\x85r\n\x01\x00\x00Rr\x0b\x01\x00\x00\x86r\x0c\x01\x00\x00}r\r\x01\x00\x00X\x0b\x00\x00\x00__wrapped__r\x0e\x01\x00\x00j\t\x01\x00\x00sNtr\x0f\x01\x00\x00Rr\x10\x01\x00\x00X\x06\x00\x00\x00__eq__r\x11\x01\x00\x00h\x0b(h\x0c(K\x02K\x00K\x02K\x05KCC8|\x01j\x00|\x00j\x00k\x08r4|\x00j\x01|\x00j\x02|\x00j\x03|\x00j\x04f\x04|\x01j\x01|\x01j\x02|\x01j\x03|\x01j\x04f\x04k\x02S\x00t\x05S\x00r\x12\x01\x00\x00N\x85r\x13\x01\x00\x00(j\x00\x01\x00\x00hfhuhvhwX\x0e\x00\x00\x00NotImplementedr\x14\x01\x00\x00tr\x15\x01\x00\x00h\xc9X\x05\x00\x00\x00otherr\x16\x01\x00\x00\x86r\x17\x01\x00\x00h\xcbj\x11\x01\x00\x00K\x01C\x06\x00\x01\x0c\x01(\x01r\x18\x01\x00\x00))tr\x19\x01\x00\x00Rr\x1a\x01\x00\x00cdataclasses\n__dict__\nj\x11\x01\x00\x00NN}r\x1b\x01\x00\x00Ntr\x1c\x01\x00\x00Rr\x1d\x01\x00\x00X\x08\x00\x00\x00__hash__r\x1e\x01\x00\x00Nhf]r\x1f\x01\x00\x00(X\x0f\x00\x00\x00peter@yahoo.comr \x01\x00\x00X\x0e\x00\x00\x00mark@yahoo.comr!\x01\x00\x00X\x0f\x00\x00\x00alysa@yahoo.comr"\x01\x00\x00ehuh\x8chvh\x8dhw}r#\x01\x00\x00(h\x8eGA\xd8"d\xb2\xfa\xa9\x94h\x8fK\x03uutr$\x01\x00\x00Rr%\x01\x00\x00.'

c = dill.loads(data_stream)
print(c)

"""
output:
{
    "email_list": [
        "peter@yahoo.com",
        "mark@yahoo.com",
        "alysa@yahoo.com"
    ],
    "message": "Foo bar fizzbuzz",
    "subject": "Sample Issue",
    "info": {
        "time": 1619628747.9166002,
        "count": 3
    }
}
"""
```

Comment: Related question [here (using pickle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647566/pickle-a-dynamically-parameterized-sub-class/). Yes, this is possible via using a custom metaclass and `copyreg`. See also [issue 7689](https://bugs.python.org/issue7689).

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue `dill` needed the metaclass type register for marshalling. Below is the updated metaclass and type registration for dill that solved the issue.

#### Updated Metaclass

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple

from core.util.errors import OptionalModuleError, InvalidRequest

import json
from collections import defaultdict

try:
    from flask import request
except ImportError:
    raise OptionalModuleError("metaclasses.JSONRequest", ["flask"])


class JSONRequest(type):
    """
    This is a metaclass used to autonomously populate dataclasses with the request data coming in to flask

    NOTE: This metaclass only works with dataclasses

    Optional Parameter:
        inp: **kwargs dict or a class attribute that is a callable that produces a dictionary
    """
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if "inp" in kwargs:
            inp = kwargs["inp"]
        elif "inp" in cls.__dict__:
            inp = cls.__dict__["inp"]()
        else:
            inp = request.json
        cls.__initialize(inp)
        return cls

    def __initialize(cls, inp: Dict) -> None:
        """
        Initializes all of the dataclasses fields

        If the field is missing in the JSON request and it does not have a default value in the data class a
        InvalidRequest error will be raised. Additionally if the Json value is [], {}, "" will default to the default
        value, and if the default value is missing an InvalidRequest error will also be raised.

        Parameters:
            inp: Json input
        """
        json = defaultdict(lambda: None)
        json.update(inp)

        for name, _ in cls.__dataclass_fields__.items():
            if (not json[name]) and (name not in cls.__dict__.keys()):
                raise InvalidRequest(f"Request is missing the {name} field")

            value = json[name] or cls.__dict__[name]
            setattr(cls, name, value)

    def _get_fields(cls) -> Dict:
        """
        This method returns all of the dataclasses fields
        
        Returns:
             Dict/JSON representation of the dataclasses attributes
        """
        return {name: getattr(cls, name) for name, _ in cls.__dataclass_fields__.items()}

    def get_info(cls) -> Tuple[str, str, Dict]:
        """
        This method returns all the needed information to reconstruct/deserialize the class
        
        Returns:
            Tuple containing the dataclass' module location and name for importing it when deserializing and the 
            input used to repopulate the class to it last state  
        """
        return cls.__module__, cls.__name__, cls._get_fields()

    def __str__(cls) -> str:
        """
        Method to print the request nicely
        
        Returns:
            The str representation of the class
        """
        return json.dumps(cls._get_fields(), indent=4)
```

#### Dill Type Registration

```
def recreate_request(mod_name: str, class_name: str, inp: Dict) -> JSONRequest:
    """
    Method to rebuild the serialized request

    Parameters:
        mod_name: The name of the dataclass' module
        class_name: The name of the dataclass
        inp: The state of the dataclass' member variables
        
    Returns:
        The deserialized JSON Request with its last known state
    """
    mod = __import__(mod_name, fromlist=[class_name])
    klass = getattr(mod, class_name)
    return klass(inp=inp)


@dill.register(JSONRequest)
def reduce_request(pickler, obj):
    """
    This method registers recreate_request for all dataclasses with a metaclass of JSONRequest
    
    Parameter:
        pickler: The pickler from the dill library
        obj: The dataclass being serialized
    """
    args = obj.get_info()
    pickler.save_reduce(recreate_request, args, obj=obj)
```