# Pickling dynamically created classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I would like to create a class with specified base classes dynamically. In order to do it, I implemented the following:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

def create(cls):
    class C(A, cls):
        def __reduce__(self):
            print("REDUCE")
            return (create, (self.__class__.__bases__[-1],))
    return C()
```

Note that I also added a custom `__reduce__` to support pickle dumping. However, it works only of instances of the created class(because `__reduce__` is not a class method).

```
import pickle
c = create(B)
pickle.dumps(c)  # Success
pickle.dumps(c.__class__)  # Error
```

```
REDUCE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-25510ddce378> in <module>
      2 c = create(B)
      3 pickle.dumps(c)
----> 4 pickle.dumps(c.__class__)

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'create.<locals>.C'
```

How could I make the class itself to support pickle dumping?

Comment: I don't realy get what you want to do with that, what's the goal form creating a method that returns a class and take a another class `cls` just for nothing also the `A` class in it where's it's goal in all that

Comment: Having some class (let's call it B), the goal is to create another class which inherits from B and A. I would like to do this creation in the runtime for many classes. In this concrete question, I just use the simple B to show the actual problem.

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647566/pickle-a-dynamically-parameterized-sub-class/). Yes, this is possible via using a custom metaclass and `copyreg`. See also [issue 7689](https://bugs.python.org/issue7689).

Answer (score 0):

first you should know that `__class__` is an attribute on the object that refers to the class from which the object was created.
and from what you said I think this method answer it:

```
def create(cls):
     class C(A, cls):
         def classes(self):
             return A, cls
     return C()
```